# X scale gets messed up when adding series with different numbers of data points to chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graph, charts

I have four sets of rows of data that I'm importing into separate `Series` of data in my `Chart`.

```
DataTable digitalTest1Data = TimeBasedSortBy(GetData(null, null, "DigitalTest1"), precision);
DataTable digitalTest2Data = TimeBasedSortBy(GetData(null, null, "DigitalTest2"), precision);
DataTable digitalTest3Data = TimeBasedSortBy(GetData(null, null, "DigitalTest3"), precision);
DataTable digitalTest4Data = TimeBasedSortBy(GetData(null, null, "DigitalTest4"), precision);

Series dt1 = chart1.Series.Add("DigitalTester 1");
Series dt2 = chart1.Series.Add("DigitalTester 2");
Series dt3 = chart1.Series.Add("DigitalTester 3");
Series dt4 = chart1.Series.Add("DigitalTester 4");

dt1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
dt2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
dt3.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
dt4.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

dt1.BorderWidth = 5;
dt2.BorderWidth = 5;
dt3.BorderWidth = 5;
dt4.BorderWidth = 5;

foreach (DataRow row in digitalTest1Data.Rows)
{
    dt1.Points.AddXY(row[0], row[5]);
}
foreach (DataRow row in digitalTest2Data.Rows)
{
    dt2.Points.AddXY(row[0], row[5]);
}
foreach (DataRow row in digitalTest3Data.Rows)
{
    dt3.Points.AddXY(row[0], row[5]);
}
foreach (DataRow row in digitalTest4Data.Rows)
{
    dt4.Points.AddXY(row[0], row[5]);
}
```

However, it doesn't line up on the X axis:

[image: All four]

But, when I comment out the first two `foreach` blocks (for `dt1` and `dt2`), numbers three and four work perfectly together! <sub>(Note that they continue to 7/31/2018 as they should instead of halting at 3/29.)</sub>

[image: Just two]

If I uncomment either of the blocks, the issue returns:

[image: Three this time]

My best guess for the reason for the problem is that the fact that they have different numbers of data points is confusing the chart.  `DigitalTester1` has 12 points, `2` has 11, `3` has 8, and `4` has 8.  However, I would think that the chart would find the matching x values and match them together!  I might be missing data in the middle, but I think `dt3` and `dt4` just don't have data for the first 4 months or so.

Comment: What is the datatype of `row[0]`? I guess they are not dates but strings, which would explain why they can't be matched!

Comment: Absolutely genius.  Wow, I converted `DateTime` to `String` so it would display, not realizing that they both work.  Thanks!  I guess here I stand for future Googlers like me who follow :)

Comment: At least half of MSChart related question boil down to this :-) - you can still use the `series.LabelFormat` to format the dates as you wish..